# Programmatically import ROOT certificate to "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, ssl-certificate

### Que :  How to *programmatically* **import ROOT certificate** to "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" in Google Chrome via **Chrome Extension**?

I am developing a Chrome Extension and I want to import Root Certificate in:

#### chrome://chrome/settings/

#### Manage Certificates --> Trusted Root Certification Authorities --> Import

Is there any **API** for *Google Chrome Extension* ? or javascript code? to achieve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Nope. The documentation does not list such a feature: [API index](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/api_index.html), [experimental API index](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/experimental.html).

Comment: @RobW: Okay, Is there any **Javascript API** (something like jQuery) to do this ?

Comment: The Chrome extension API is a superset of the JavaScript API. So, that's definitely not possible

Comment: This would be nice. I was looking to do the same, but I may end up using [startssl's free cert](http://www.startssl.com/?app=1). Maybe that is a solution.

Comment: Beware: I actually just found out that, [per their policy pdf](https://www.startssl.com/policy-addendum-2010.pdf), the free "class 1" certs that startcom offers can only be used in non-commercial applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of such an alternative in Chrome. But in any case, I doubt it exist as it would be a **huge** security hole.

Meaning that a malicious extension could silently register expired or non trusted certificates. Thereafter, if the user visits the domain of the certificate, it wouldn't be alerted of the potential dangers of the non-trusted cert.

As usual, it would be great to have such a functionality if your intentions are good, but you just can't take the risk!